# Multiple desktops not working in bspwm | bspwmrc not being read?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with Gnome desktop environment.

A few days ago I decided to give bspwm a try and it's working fine except for one thing... I can't use multiple desktops(similar to workspaces in windows). I researched a bit and now it seems that bspwm isn't reading my bspwmrc in the first place.

I have placed my configs as `{HOME}/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc` and `{HOME}/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` and both of them are executables.

At some places, I found the mention of xinitrc but I haven't configured anything there. I didn't have a xinitrc in my home directory in the first place. I found one here `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` and it had this:-

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

I copied it to my home directory and added a few lines. Now it reads this:-

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
#. /etc/X11/Xsession

sxhkd &
exec bspwm
```

And my bspwmrc file (which is currently not being read btw) is this:-

```
#! /bin/sh

pkill sxhkd
sxhkd &
pkill compton
compton &
pkill feh 
feh --randomize --bg-fill ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/ &

pkill polybar
polybar example

bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

If I run this

```
bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

in the terminal then I can see these desktops on the top bar and can easily switch between them.

But the problem is why my bspwmrc is not being read by bspwm in the first place??
Please help!!

Edit: I noticed that **my bspwmrc is being read by bspwm** because whenever I tried to make some changes to my bspwmrc (in this case I played with the `feh` conguration in the bspwmrc file), all those changes are being reflected except the monitor thing!!

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on Reddit. To read about all of it check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bspwm/comments/k93ar7/multiple_desktops_not_working_in_bspwm_bspwmrc/) out.

I added `eDP-1` to my bspc monitor line and now it is this:-

```
bspc monitor eDP-1 -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X
```

But even this didn't help so I tried to **log stderr from bspwmrc** with the help of

```
set -xv
exec 2>>/tmp/bspwm.log
```

and I found out that the problem was actually with my polybar configuration( I had just copied the default polybar config for now having the `"polybar example"`), due to which the rest of bspwmrc wasn't completely read. The polybar config was generating errors like these,

```
polybar|warn:  Dropping unmatched character  (U+e0ca) in ''
polybar|warn:  Dropping unmatched character  (U+e016) in ''
polybar|warn:  Dropping unmatched character  (U+e10c) in ''
```

So, I just moved the bspc monitor line before I started my polybar, and then it worked perfectly fine.
Now, my bspwmrc is this,

```
#! /bin/sh

set -xv
exec 2>>/tmp/bspwm.log

bspc query -M --names
bspc monitor eDP-1 -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X

pkill sxhkd
sxhkd &
pkill compton
compton &
pkill feh 
feh --randomize --bg-fill ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/ &

pkill polybar
polybar example

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

Now I just have to tweak my polybar config a bit and it will also work fine.